# HTML table automatically expand last column to occupy remaining width

Tags: html, css

I have a table structure which looks like below;

```
<table style="width: 100%; display: flex; flex-flow: column; table-layout: fixed">
<thead style="width: 100%">
<th style="width: 10%; min-width: 10rem">Col1</th>
<th style="width: 20%; min-width: 20rem">Col2</th>
<th style="width: 30%; min-width: 30rem">Col3</th>
<th>Col with no explicit width defined (I want this col to expand)</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Col1</td>
<td>Col2</td>
<td>Col3</td>
<td>Col4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now my simple question is I want the last column to have flexible width i.e. it should occupy whatever is the remaining width (depending on the screen resolution, etc)

However, it seems to be taking only the required space and not automatically expanding to take rest of the space. Is that something which is possible to do with the table layout ?

Comment: remove the  flex properties if you want to use the table-layout properties.

Comment: The `width` on the `thead` will be ignored unless you change its `display` property...

Answer (score 1):

`display: flex` overwrites the tables default display mode `display: table`, which you need. Remove it (and `flex-flow: column;`).